# Regex for select middle word separate by space

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to select the word that start with '/' that place somewhere in the line

**Example**

```
30 8 * * * /root/something > /dev/null 2>&1
30 8 * * * usr/bin/php /home/php/script/run.php
```

I want to match

```
/root/something
/home/php/script/run.php
```

My regex doesn't works at all (using Ansible)

```
regex_findall('\\s(/.*)')
```

and that give output like this

```
/root/something > /dev/null 2>&1
/home/php/script/run.php"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\s(/\S+).*'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6F2cRT/1)

It will match a whitespace (`\s`), then will capture `/` and then any 1+ non-whitespace chars (`\S+`) into Group 1, and then will match the rest of the line (with `.*`).

Another idea: match sequences `/` and then 1+ chars other than `/` if not starting with `/dev/null`:

```
r'(?<!\S)(?!/dev/null)(?:/[^/\s]+)+'
```

This will match

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string should appear immediately on the left
- `(?!/dev/null)` - no `/dev/null` is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?:/[^/\s]+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `[^/\s]+` - 1+ chars other than `/` and whitespace.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6F2cRT/2).